# lispworks and sbcl

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

First of all, I'm forced to use LispWorks and I would like to know what compiler does it actually use and whether I can use it in CLI. Also in LispWorks there are methods like `defsystem` etc., are they somehow built in the environment or do they form a package I can actually load (for example) in `sbcl` REPL?

Comment: Is it still acceptable to say [RTFM](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/index.html)? LispWorks has *excellent* documentation (they're the canonical source of the CLHS!) and reading it is *completely* worth your while.

Answer (score 6):

[LispWorks](http://www.lispworks.com/) is a *commercial* Common Lisp implementation that includes its *own* compiler, debugger, profiler, IDE &c &c.

It comes with its own [`defsystem`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/LW/html/lw-153.htm) *macro* (not *method*!) as well as [`adsf`](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/).

I strongly recommend that you consult the documentation that came with the software.

Comment: Recent LW also comes with ASDF (although possibly a mildly old version: you can update it).  So you can work compatibly in LW and, for instance, SBCL.  (Not disagreeing with your answer!)

Answer (score 5):

If one has a full LispWorks version (not the Personal Edition), then one can create a version which does not start the IDE by default:

See chapter [12.4.4 Saving a non-windowing image](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/RNIG/html/readme-105.htm#pgfId-907191)